Trouble installing current version TeXLive on Linux Mint
I recently reinstalled Mint on a new device, and installed all my programs, including TeXstudio and TeXLive. I ran into an issue that I don’t think I had on my previous device, because I think I had managed to install a more current version of TeXLive than is available in the Mint repo. However, I'm now unable to do that.
I've tried both the Quick Install instructions (here: https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)
and the more elaborate ones (here: https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-140003)
both seem to process and finish correctly, then I check the version via pdftex --version and it shows up as the same version from 2021 as is in the Mint repo.
So I purged all those files again, and downloaded the DVD iso and that actually made the --version show up as being from 2024, however then TeXstudio threw me an error, something about not finding LuaLaTeX. I thought I just had to refresh, so I logged out and back in, and then the terminal wasn't showing me any TeX installations at all, e.g. pdftex --version was telling me it's not installed, same for lualatex, etc.
So now for the fourth time I'm trying the net installer, but I doubt the fifth time will be the charm.
What am I doing wrong? My goal is to install a current version of LaTeX.
Thanks!

most likely you have not set the PATH in the shell from which texstudio is launched

How would I do that? I've finished the install, and added this to my .bashrc file: PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH

so probably if you start texstudio from a shell it would work but you started it from some desktop shortcut that is set at a higher level you may need to set it in .profile or .login or .something depending on your system, there are some answers on this site..., but first check if you just cd to your document and type pdflatex yourfile.tex that it works, the rest is just editor setup not really releated to texlive install

adding it to .profile worked!

glad you got it working, sorry about the automated text above:-) comes from marking it as duplicate.
